# PrimeFaces picklist target not populated

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I'm implementing a PrimeFaces picklist in a dialog. Everytime the dialog is shown the contents of the target of the picklist should change depending on a list entry shown before. Before I open the dialog I fill the target of the picklist in ProdukteBean.onEditProdukt(..)  with the appropriate values. Unfortunately these target values do not show up in the target container. Here are the relevant code pieces:

list.xhtml:

```xml
<p:commandLink id="editButton" update=":dialogForm:editDialogPanel" title="Edit" 
    oncomplete="produktDialog.show();" 
    process="@this" partialSubmit="true"
    action="#{produkteBean.onEditProdukt}">
            <h:outputText value="Bearbeiten" /> 
            <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{p}" target="#{produkteBean.produkt}" /> 
</p:commandLink>
```

dialog.xhtml:

```xml
<!-- ... -->
<p:dialog id="dialog" header="Produkt-Details" widgetVar="produktDialog" appendToBody="true" showEffect="explode" hideEffect="explode"  modal="true" width="500"> 
<p:messages id="msgs"/> 
        <h:form id="dialogForm"> 
            <!-- ... -->
            <p:pickList id="produkteDatenList" var="proddat" value="#{produkteBean.datenList}"
        itemLabel="#{proddat.bezeichnung}" itemValue="#{proddat}" 
        converter="produktDatConverter"/> 
            <!-- ... -->
        </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

ProdukteBean.java:

```java
    @Named("produkteBean")
    @ViewScoped // @SessionScoped // @ViewScoped
    public class ProdukteBean implements Serializable {

        @Inject @Transient private ProdukteService produkteService; 
        @Inject @Transient private DatenService datenService; 

        @Inject()
        private ProdukteDatenBean produkteDatenBean;

        private DualListModel<Dat> datenList = new DualListModel<Dat>();  

        private Dat dat = null;

        public ProdukteBean() {

        }

        @PostConstruct
        private void init() {

            getAll();
        }

        private void getAll() {
            logger.debug("getAll()");
            getAllProdukte();
            getAllDaten();
        }

        private void getAllDaten() {
            logger.debug("getAllDaten()");

            List<Dat> source = new ArrayList<Dat>();
            source.addAll(datenService.list());

            List<Dat> target = new ArrayList<Dat>();
            if (produkt.getDaten() != null) {
                logger.debug("adding " + produkt.getDaten().size() + " daten to produkt " + produkt.getName());
                target.addAll(produkt.getDaten());
            }       

            DualListModel<Dat> datenList = new DualListModel<Dat>();  
            datenList.setSource(source);
            datenList.setTarget(target);
            setDatenList(datenList);
        }

        public List<Produkt> getAllProdukte() {
            logger.debug("getAllProdukte()");
            return produkteService.list();
        }

        public void onEditProdukt() {

            onEditProdukt(null);
        }

        public void onEditProdukt(ActionEvent actionEvent) {

            logger.debug("onEditProdukt: " + ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(produkt));
            if (produkt != null) {
                setSelectedEinheit(produkt.getEinheit());
                getAllDaten();
            }
            FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Produkt ausgewählt", produkt.getName());  
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);  
        }

        /**
         * @return the einheitList
         */
        public List<Einheit> getEinheitList() {

            if (einheitList == null) {
                einheitList = produkteService.getEinheiten();
            }
            return einheitList;
        }

    }
```

ProduktDatConverter.java:

```java
@FacesConverter(forClass=Dat.class,value="produktDatConverter")
@ViewScoped
public class ProduktDatConverter implements Converter {

@Inject
@Transient DatenService datenService;

@Transient
protected final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName());

    // gets never called (of course)
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, String str) {
       logger.debug("getAsObject(): " + str);
       return null;
    }

public String getAsString(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, Object object) {
   if (object instanceof Dat) {
            // logger.debug("   returning id " + String.valueOf(((Dat) object).getId()));
        return Long.toString(((Dat) object).getId());
   }
   return null;
}
}
```

Any ideas? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Please remove unnecessary code.

Comment: Ok, removed unnecessary code. Sorry.

Comment: Is `datenList` attribute being properly created into the backing bean? Debug it and check that the proper values are being set and you will be able to isolate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `@ViewScoped` along CDI Managed Bean. Change it to JSF Managed Bean. Better, use [CODI](http://myfaces.apache.org/extensions/cdi/) instead

Also see:

- [View Scope in CDI Weld](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/4865047/view-scope-in-cdi-weld/5122139)
- [CDI missing @ViewScoped and @FlashScoped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7812985/cdi-missing-viewscoped-and-flashscoped)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it's `converter` + `injection` problem. Please, click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7531449/cdi-injection-into-a-facesconverter) and refer to the BalusC answer. You can also try to replace:

`@FacesConverter(forClass=Dat.class,value="produktDatConverter")`

`@ViewScoped`

with

`@ManagedBean`

`@RequestScoped`

and call the converter like this:
`converter="#{produktDatConverter}"`

Comment: Thank you. I tried that and also changed all the 

`@Named`

annotations to 

`@ManagedBean`

and the 

`@Inject`

annotations to 

`@ManagedProperty`

I also double-checked that the backing bean values are in-place and they are. Unfortunately it still doesn't work ...